# Smarter looping over permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've got a 3 by 3 grid of boolean values, and I'm interested in the number of ways I can have exactly three "living" cells (there's 56 permutations, by my count). Rotational symmetries don't matter, but the living cells are indistinguishable from each other.

Assuming that I'm indexing the values in the grid relative to the centroid:

```
-------------------
|-1,-1| 0,-1| 1,-1|
-------------------
|-1,0 |     | 1,0 |
-------------------
|-1,1 | 0,1 | 1,1 |
-------------------
```

is there a nice loop that I could use to calculate the 56 permutations? (I've just finished typing it all out, and I'd love to know if I could have been slightly smarter).

I'm using C++, but a basic algorithm would be wonderful in any language or pseudo-language, if it's clear.

Comment: Look into `std::next_permutation` in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: how did you get 56 permutations? `9 choose 3` = 84 there are 84 distinct combinations.

Comment: @twain249 - He's not including centroid cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [next_permutation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/next_permutation.html).

For example, assume string each character in x below represents the a cell in the grid (except centroid cell) starting at top left and going to bottom right. You could run this code to find all the possible arrangements, and inside the loop, string x will represent a possible arrangement, where 1 is a live cell, and 0 is a dead one.

```
int main() {
  string x = "00000111";
  int cnt = 0;
  do {
    ++cnt;

    // do something useful with this configuration...

  } while(next_permutation(x.begin(),x.end()));
  cout<<cnt<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the link has gone dead after 7 years. For those who really want to click a link: [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) from Wikipedia.

> The following algorithm generates the next permutation lexicographically after a given permutation. It changes the given permutation in-place.
>
> 1. Find the largest index k such that a[k] < a[k + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
> 2. Find the largest index l such that a[k] < a[l]. Since k + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies k < l.
> 3. Swap a[k] with a[l].
> 4. Reverse the sequence from a[k + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].

Comment: Link ≠ answer. Please include at least a summary of the contents of the link in your answer (to prevent link rot).

Answer (score 0):

you could use this method:

assume you represent your grid with an array, where your elements are

```
[(-1,-1), (0,-1),(1,-1)...]
```

and so on, you basically take element in the first line, then second line, then third line.

So now, you just have to take all the available numbers you have, that is to say:

```
[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

as you said you only want 3 living cells.

now that we decided wha tdifferent strings mean, you can simply take a code which performs permutation, like the xcellnt one at this link [How To Generate Permutation In C?](http://techforum4u.com/entry.php/764-How-To-Generate-Permutation-In-C?s=ff4d4f39e832033a81526994f6fe1a19&bt=953#comment953)
hich does exactly what you want, or any ohte equivalent code like std::next_permutation which is in the algorithm library.

Answer (score 0):

Do you prefer "**smarter**" looping or "**saner**"?

```
//c++ --std=c++11 test.cc

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

using std::string;
using std::list;
using std::vector;

const string show[8] = { "(-1,-1)","( 0,-1)","( 1,-1)"
                       , "(-1, 0)",          "( 1, 0)"
                       , "(-1, 1)","( 0, 1)","( 1, 1)"
                       };

auto permutations_of_living_cells =
    [] (int number_of_living_cells) -> list<vector<string>>
    {
    typedef list<vector<string>> (*recT)( void*
                                        , int
                                        , int
                                        , vector<string> &&
                                        , list<vector<string>> &&
                                        );
    recT rec = []( void*r
                 , int n
                 , int i
                 , vector<string> && prefix
                 , list<vector<string>> && l
                 ) -> list<vector<string>>
        {
        if( n==0 )
            {
            l.push_back(std::move(prefix));
            return std::move(l);
            }
        if( i>8-n ) return std::move(l);
        vector<string> psi(prefix);
        psi.push_back(show[i]);
        return  ((recT)r)(r,n  ,i+1,std::move(prefix),
                ((recT)r)(r,n-1,i+1,std::move(psi   ),
                    std::move(l)
                )
                );
        };
    return rec( (void*)rec
              , number_of_living_cells
              , 0
              , vector<string>()
              , list<vector<string>>()
              );
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream & out,const vector<T> & v )
{
    if( v.empty() ) return out << "[]";
    out << "[ " << *v.begin();
    std::for_each( v.begin()+1, v.end(), [&](T x){out<<", "<<x;} );
    return out << " ]";
}

int main()
{
    for( auto v : permutations_of_living_cells(3) )
        std::cout << v << "\n";
    std::cout << std::flush;
    return 0;
}
```